# Angularjs with Django using AJAX request

Tags: python, ajax, django, angularjs

I sent a information by Post method until one views in Django and returned to the site. However, I'm not getting submit this information on the site.

File post3.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function ListDropdown($scope, $http){               
            $scope.ccvms={lista01:['1','3','5','7','9'],lista02:['2','4','6','8','10']}
            $scope.send=function(x,y){
                $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:'/escalar',
                data:x+y,
                headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                }).success(function(c){
                      console.log(c)
                })
            }
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ListDropdown">
        <select ng-model="ccvm" ng-options="ccvm as ccvm for (ccvm, nums) in ccvms"></select>
        <select ng-model="num" ng-disabled="!ccvm" ng-options="num for num in ccvms[ccvm]" ng-change="send(num, ccvm)"></select>
        <h1 ng-model=c>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

File views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def post3(request):
    return render_to_response("post3.html")

@csrf_exempt
def escalando(z):
    x=list(z.POST)
    c=str(x[0])+"_retornou"
    return HttpResponse(c)
```

File urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^post3/','bvmfconsulta.views.post3'),
    url(r'^escalar','bvmfconsulta.views.escalando'),
)
```

Appears in the console.log(c) the information, for example "4lista02_retornou", however, I am not getting insert it on the site.

Comment: After you have recieved data through AJAX call you should make it visible by angular by setting `$scope.ccvm = c`

Comment: Thank you. The success function was `success(function(c){$c=scope.ccvm})` and the h1 was `<h1 ng-bind="cvm"></h1>`. However, because of ng-bind this first appearing the option of select ng-model="ccvm" and Django's response appears later. I need only to appear Django's response.

Comment: I resolved as follows: `function ListDropdown(scope, $http){$scope.resposta="" ......... success(function(c){$scope.resposta=c})}}` and h1 tag `<h1 ng-bind="resposta"></h1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.27/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function ListDropdown($scope, $http){               
        $scope.ccvms={lista01:['1','3','5','7','9'],lista02:['2','4','6','8','10']}
        $scope.resposta=""
        $scope.send=function(x,y){
            $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'/escalar',
            data:x+y,
            headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            }).success(function(c){
                  $scope.resposta=c
            })
        }
    } 
</script>

<h1 ng-bind="resposta"></h1>
```